# Is there a way to simplify the try-catch block within another try-catch-finally block?

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

I'm new to Java and is trying to learn the concept of catching exception. I saw this code online, and it has a try-catch block within the body of another try-catch-finally block. I was just wondering if there is any way to simplify the code so it can be written in a clearer manner?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Properties p1 = new Properties();
    OutputStream os1 = null;

    try {
        os1 = new FileOutputStream("xanadu123.properties");

        //set the properties value
        p1.setProperty("database", "localhost");
        p1.setProperty("1", "one");
        p1.setProperty("2", "two");

        p1.store(os1, "this is the comment");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (os1 != null) {
            try {
                os1.close();
            } catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }   
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is indeed a very common pattern, so a special syntax has been added to Java recently: [try-with-resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)

You can do

```
try(OutputStream os1 = new FileOutputStream("xanadu123.properties")){
}
catch (WhatYouHadBefore e){}
// no more finally, unless you want it for something else
```

This will be `finally` closed automatically (even without a `finally` block) and any errors during closing will be suppressed.

Answer (score 1):

According to javadocs, in Java SE 7 and later, you can use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) and it will automatically close resources when it is finished.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Properties p1 = new Properties();
    OutputStream os1 = null;
    try(os1 = new FileOutputStream("xanadu123.properties")){ //set the properties value
        p1.setProperty("database", "localhost");
        p1.setProperty("1", "one");
        p1.setProperty("2", "two");
        p1.store(os1, "this is the comment");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```